# ios app using Firebase and the correct way to sync posts

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an Instagram style app where i have users upload images and comments/favorite them. My backend is Firebase and I am using Swift 2.3.

I am running into a problem with this. Currently I am using

```
FirebaseREF.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
```

to observe for any new posts or when anyone bookmarks or likes a post. Trouble is when I have multiple users signed in, and users upload/modify posts, the UItableview on my app will scroll up or down depending on if a post is added or deleted. ( as it is syncing realtime with Firebase)

So my question is, what is the right way todo this ? How would I implement something like Instagram/twitter where I download a set number of posts, I can view in real time any changes with the post on my screen and when I pull to refresh, the new posts get downloaded ?

I do not want to register just for a single event with Firebase as then my posts don't get updated when someone likes/bookmarks a post and I would have to reload the tableview to get updated everytime.

I do have the Pull to refresh part working. The problem is right now my app responds to all realtime events and keeps scrolling/refreshing when there is any activity in the backend and this makes for a real poor experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the [tableView.visibleCells](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614896-visiblecells) and figure out which one is at the top of the screen and what its offset is relative to the tableView (Use [UIView.convertPoint:toView:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622442-convertpoint).  After you update the tableView, assuming you haven't deleted this cell, you can scroll to it with [UITableView.scrollToRowat:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614997-scrolltorow) (make sure animated is false) and restore its original offset relative to the tableView with [tableView.setContentOffset:animated](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview/1619400-setcontentoffset?language=objc) (inherited form UIScrollView).

Comment: Don't the cells get reused though ? I tried looking at tableview.visiblecells and they seem to have the same information...

Comment: They have the same information if none of the visible cells have changed.  but isn't what you want for the tableview not to scroll when changes are made?  You want the cell at the top to stay at the top so that the tableview maintains its relative position even as its content changes.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was as I scrolled down, the tableview.visiblecells.startindex and endindex kept changing between 0 &1. So I am not clear on how I would identify that particular cell and scroll back to it.

Comment: You do not use startIndex as and indexPath for the tableView; startIndex is just the index within the array of visible cells and since you are asking for the top one you expect it to always be 0 or 1; use UITableView.indexPathForCell(visibleCells[0]) https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614881-indexpathforcell

Comment: Thanks so much Josh for staying with me on this. I tried this in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

 print ("\nIndex is \(tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(cell.center))")

and then do this when i reload tableView:

tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(self.currentViewIndexPath!, atScrollPosition: .Middle, animated: false)

I think I can use this index to get the same  right ?